# Jump to cell clicking on button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel vb code in which i made a button in excel when clicked go to next sheet and search for the value based on employee number. I used Vlookup in this code. My problem is the cursor should go to the searched cell directly. My code goes below:-

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()  
 Sheets("Sheet2").Activate  

Dim rng As Range  
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet  
Dim MyStringVar1 As String  

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")   
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")   
Set rng = ws1.Range("c4")   

With ws1     

   MyStringVar1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, ws2.Range("b3:n13").Value, 5, False)   

    On Error GoTo 0    
   If MyStringVar1 = "" Then MsgBox "Item not found" Else MsgBox MyStringVar1   

End With    


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `select` instead of `msgbox`

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()  

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate  

Dim rng As Range  
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet  
Dim MyStringVar1 As String  

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")   
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")   
Set rng = ws1.Range("c4")   

With ws1     

   MyStringVar1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, ws2.Range("b3:n13").Value, 5, False)   

    On Error GoTo 0    
   If MyStringVar1 = "" Then MsgBox "Item not found" Else MyStringVar1.Select

End With    


End Sub
```

Comment: Tom its not working still< giving error invalid qualifier MyStringVar1.Select

Answer (score 0):

Try find instead.

```
Sub UsingFind()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range, lookRng As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With sh
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(Rws, "B"))
    End With

    Set lookRng = ws.Range("C4")
    Set c = Rng.Find(what:=lookRng, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto Reference:=c.OFFSET(0,4)
    Else: MsgBox "Not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

[Find data in another sheet](http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Find%20Data%20in%20other%20Sheet)

Comment: Sorry Davesexcel, I want to tell u that I have value in cell C4 in Sheet1 which is an employee number, and when button in sheet1 is clicked it will look for the the value in  Sheet2 and when that employee number found the cursor will go to the coloumn no. 5 ...

Comment: Sorry Davesexcel, I want to tell u that I have value in cell C4 in Sheet1 which is an employee number, and when button in sheet1 is clicked it will look for the the value in  Sheet2 and when that employee number found the cursor will go to the coloumn no. 5 ...

Comment: Oh yes, I changed it to search column B and then it should go to column "F"

Comment: The same thing i am doing with userform in excel. Now I have a textbox1 for employee number and textbox2 for employee name, the same is in sheet2 with ColumnA and ColumnB> Now when i enter the employee number in textbox1 the name is appearing in textbox2 and also a button to change the value of textbox2. I want the button when clicked go to the    corresponding name field..

Comment: "Thanks Davesexcel, this code is working for button in sheet.... Thanks"- You could mark my answer as the answer, then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

i would advice you to depend strictly on VB code by using for loop
scanning sheet2 column 1 for the equal value, once found it will set the focus on the same row column 5, in the below example code will check for only 10 rows you can adjust that as you like.

```
Sub usingvbonly()
Dim key As String
Sheets("sheet1").Select
key = Cells(4, 3).Value 'Value in sheet1 range("C4")
Sheets("sheet2").Select
For i = 1 To 10 Step 1
If Cells(i, 1).Value = key Then
Cells(i, 5).Select
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @nad- My answer is VBA only.